# Using CSS and JS in spring web-project

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I know that at stackoverflow are some topic about static content in Spring Web-Application, but after reading 5 of it and a lots of trying, i still can't saw my content of the page. 
I think that I have correct path on my jsp file. My project structure seams like below:

[image: My project structure]

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value = '/css/stylesheet.css' />" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value = '/js/restful.js' />"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Snore-O-Meter</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:HelloWorld()">Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But I think that is something in default values of web.xml or mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Thank You for any help, I know that is my ignorance of topic, but I had 2 books about Spring and I can't find any useful information about this topic, and I really need working real application to learn spring and creation web-application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your all your resource folders (css, js, fonts, images, etc.) under a common `resources` folder. Then add a resource handler

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

You can then change your mapping to, for example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value = '/resources/js/restful.js' />"></script>
```